# MaterialDesign SlidingTabLayout is not displaying tabs properly

Tags: android, material-design, android-sliding, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am working on MaterialDesign Tabs with Navigation drawer.I am following below example reference for integrating with my app.

https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidMaterialDesignToolbar

I just imported this project into my eclipse and just run into my mobile. But the screenshot cuts the tab text last character for eg 2 and 3 all.

[image: screen]

so how can i resolve that issue and display the full text in tab.please suggest me how i can do that.thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried it but i haven't get output as expected.better to go with below example.https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs